# как создавались пакеты для Golang

Tags: golang

Объясните как создаются пакеты в GO! Как создать свой пакет я в курсе, меня интересует как создавался САМЫЙ первый пакет скажем http, он написан на GO? Или писался на другом языке, вообщем не понимаю как все это происходит на начальном этапе, и статьи нигде найти не могу... Если он писался на GO то откуда берутся все функции и т.д...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почти весь golang написан на go (с версии 1.5), за исключением некоторых "системных" пакетов, например пакет [syscall](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/syscall) (там низкоуровневые ассемблерные вставки)

[http](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/net/http) написан целиком на golang

до 1.5 многие функции были написаны на С, скомпилированны в динамически подключаемые библиотеки и вызывались из go, как обычные функции (собственно так до сих пор можно делать даже со своими библиотеками на С)

собственно, рано или поздно ты придешь к вопросу, а как же пишутся компиляторы (трансляторы итд) сами на себе и/или с нуля - ответ:

> **[Раскрутка компилятора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) с использованием компилятора существующего языка**
>   Создание транслятора языка L методом раскрутки подразумевает выполнение некоторых шагов.
>
> 1. На первом шаге из языка L выделяется подмножество L0, которое не требует больших усилий для реализации, но является достаточным для написания транслятора самого себя.
> 2. Затем, используя какой-либо существующий для этой платформы язык (например, C), составляется исходный код транслятора для L0.
>      Затем на языке L0 составляется транслятор для самого языка L0. Исполняемый файл транслятора создаётся с помощью транслятора, полученного на первом шаге. После этого у программиста имеется транслятор L0, способный обработать свой исходный код.
> 3. Далее начинается постепенное расширение L0 до L: добавляется какая-либо ранее не реализованная возможность языка L, после чего предыдущей версией транслятора создаётся новая, а вновь добавленную возможность можно использовать в трансляторе для последующего расширения языка.
>      Именно этот процесс и называют **раскруткой**.
>
> Число шагов можно уменьшить, если после составления транслятора L0 на языке С сразу начинать составлять транслятор L на подмножестве L0.

Comment: Многое стало понятным, но еще раз не против в этом переубедится (правильно ли все я понял). Транслятор это преобразование кода на машинный код или байт код, или в код другого языка. Компилятор это трансляция кода в основном в машинный код. Интерпретатор это трансляция кода на лету(без создания исполняемого файла). Далее,  ГО компилятор создали на другом языке (С++) (все его функции и т.д...), после того как компилятор стал, скажем, мощным, то этот ГО компилятор (написанный на С++) скомпилировал компилятор написанный на ГО для ГО, так?

Comment: да, все так, только использовали С (без ++). Многие компиляторы создавали так же, не только go.